# TCPDF autopagebreak + backgroundimage

Tags: background-image, tcpdf

I am busy with a project that needs a lot of pdf files. Because all of them need the design of the company I use a background-image with the logo/watermark.

Everything goes fine if I have only 1 page, but when there are multiple pages, the background is only on the first.

```
$pdf->Image('bg/background.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 0, '', false, false, 0);
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setPageMark();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->writeHTML($bodyText, true, true, true, true, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('doc.pdf', 'I');
```

So my $bodyText is more then 1 page...

Is there a solution to have every page a background?

Thanks

Wouter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could extend the TCPDF class with a custom header function, and add image to header, with [`TCPDF::Image`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352). There is an example on how to do this within the [TCPDF examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_051.phps)

From the example:

```
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // set bacground image
        $img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'image_demo.jpg';
        $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}
```

And use `MYPDF` instead of `TCPDF` just as you would use `TCPDF`. The only thing I don't know if the PDF body can overlap with the header, but I think it can if you explicitly specify the margins and the header size.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: you can mark it as solution anytime, also up-vote it if you feel it deserves

Comment: It works, but what if I would like to use a different image for each instance of MYPDF ?

Comment: This works for me for the first four pages, after which the image disappears. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer from Mathe works great.***

As asked by Jasmines to use different images for each instance of MYPDF, we can have a function before custom header as:

```
var $image_name;

    public function SetImagePath($image_name)
    {
        $this->image_path =  K_PATH_IMAGES.$image_name;
    }
```

Then after we use MYPDF we can write:

```
$pdf->setImagePath($imageName)
```

And, a little change in custom header.

```
$this->Image($this->image_path, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```